# I get bean.xml file not found exception in Maven Spring project Intellij Idea but file exists in the correct path

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have a simple Spring app. created using Maven and Intellij Idea. I have 3 simple files, a Person model, an executer class and a bean.xml file for Dependency Injection.

[image: Here, is the file structure.]

```
> src
  > main
     > java
       > app
         > Client.java
       > models
         > Person.java
       personbean.xml
```

This is Person class

```
package models;

public class Person {
    String id;
    String fName;
    String lName;
    String address;
    String bGroup;

    public Person() {
        System.out.println("Person created..............");
    }

    public Person(String fName, String lName, String address, String bGroup) {
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.address = address;
        this.bGroup = bGroup;
    }
```

And this is the Client class
package app;

```
import models.Person;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("personbean.xml");

        Person p1 = context.getBean("person1", Person.class);
        System.out.println(p1);
    }
}
```

And finally this is the personbean.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean id="person1" class="models.Person">
        <property name="fName" value="John"></property>
        <property name="lName" value="Doe"></property>
        <property name="address" value="Alaska"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Now the weird thing and my question is, When I create this structure on Idea and Run the Client.java, I get FileNotFoundException. I tried several times. But when I close Idea and open the project on Eclipse, run the Client.java once, there is no problem and it executes. After this, I closed Eclipse and re-opened the project on Idea and boom! It is working. I made some research and could not find significant thing. Why is that happening, and if I go on using Idea to improve this project, will I have the same issue with every new xml file? I use IDEA 2021.2.2 Ultimate and Eclipse 2021-6 (4.20)

Comment: It should be in resources, not in sources.

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1744774)